# how to add columns in the table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to copy the existing column and it append to end of the column. Please advise.

http://jsbin.com/hucifuwuwo/1/edit?html,js,output

```
  <table id="myTable" cell>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="test"><td contenteditable="true"></td><td contenteditable="true">Names</td></tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
<input id="addrow" type="button" value="Add Row">
<input id="addcolumn" type="button" value="Add Column">
$(function(){
  $("#addrow").click(function(){
    $("#myTable tr:last").after($("<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>"));
  });
  $("#addcolumn").click(function(){
    $("#myTable tr:last").append($("<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>"));
  });

});
```

Comment: problem is in adding coloum so you have to append each row from start to end . using each method

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5QkUA/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too quite sure what your question is but this code might do it, lemme know what exactly u need:

```
$(function(){
  $("#addrow").click(function(){
    $("#myTable tr:last").after("<tr></tr>");
    $("#myTable tr:nth-child(1) td").each (function (){
    $("#myTable tr:last").append("<td></td>")
    });    
  });
  $("#addcolumn").click(function(){
    $("#myTable tr").append("<td></td>");
  });  
});
```

[Link to JSbin](http://jsbin.com/hupesahabe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 2):

Actually your add row is not true for the solution you wanted.

- Fixed your row addition
- Fixed contenteditable attribute for every cell

```js
$(function(){
  $("#addrow").click(function(){
    var tr = "<tr>" + "<td contenteditable='true'></td>".repeat($("#myTable tr:eq(0) td").length) + "</tr>"
    $("#myTable").append(tr);
  });
  $("#addcolumn").click(function(){
    $("#myTable tr").append($("<td contenteditable='true'></td>"));
  });
});
```

```css
table,tr,td
{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
</head>
<body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

  <table id="myTable" cell>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="test"><td contenteditable="true"></td><td contenteditable="true">Names</td></tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
<input id="addrow" type="button" value="Add Row">
<input id="addcolumn" type="button" value="Add Column">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the vanilla JS method `document.createElement` in conjuction with jQuery's `.append`:

```
  $("#addcolumn").click(function(){
    $("#myTable tr:last").append(document.createElement('td'));
  });
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9z7nqg6e/) for a live demo

Comment: i want to copy entire second column

Comment: even though, I add one or more rows.

Comment: @vkfjs So you want to copy the contents of the second column so that every new column has "Names" in it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your addcolumn click function as below

```
$("#addcolumn").click(function(){
    $("#myTable tr").append($("<td></td>"));

  });
```

Hope this helps